# aggregate column values at 5 min intervals and create a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe as:

```
           T1            T2           T3             timestamp
          45.37        44.48            13 2015-11-05 10:23:00
          44.94        44.55         13.37 2015-11-05 10:24:00
          45.32        44.44         13.09 2015-11-05 10:27:00
          45.46        44.51         13.29 2015-11-05 10:28:00
          45.46        44.65         13.18 2015-11-05 10:29:16
          45.96        44.85         13.23 2015-11-05 10:32:00
          45.52        44.56         13.53 2015-11-05 10:36:00
          45.36        44.62         13.25 2015-11-05 10:37:00
```

I want to create a new dataframe that contains vaules of T1, T2 and T3 aggregated over 5 min intervals based on the `timestamp` column. I did come across `aggregate` and it seems to use one of the columns to group/aggregate the corresponding values in other columns.

If no rows had values over 5-min interval, then the rows to represent `NA`s. I also like another column that indicates number items used to make the average over 5-min intervals.

Looking for a most efficient way of doing it in `R`.  Thanks

Comment: Please provide the dataset (use dput perhaps), as well as provide the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure the timestamp columns is a date.time column. You can skip this line if it already is in this format.

```
df1$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df1$timestamp)
```

xts has some nice functions for working with timeseries. Especially for rolling functions or time aggregating functions. In this case `period.apply` can help out.

```
library(xts)

# create xts object. Be sure to exclude the timestamp column otherwise you end up with a character matrix. 
df1_xts <- as.xts(df1[, -4], order.by = df1$timestamp)

# sum per 5 minute intervals
df1_xts_summed <- period.apply(df1_xts, endpoints(df1_xts, on = "minutes", k = 5), colSums)

# count rows per 5 minute interval and add to data
df1_xts_summed$nrows <- period.apply(df1_xts$T1, endpoints(df1_xts, on = "minutes", k = 5), nrow)

df1_xts_summed 

                        T1     T2    T3 nrows
2015-11-05 10:24:00  90.31  89.03 26.37     2
2015-11-05 10:29:16 136.24 133.60 39.56     3
2015-11-05 10:32:00  45.96  44.85 13.23     1
2015-11-05 10:37:00  90.88  89.18 26.78     2
```

If you want it all back into a data.frame:

```
df_final <- data.frame(timestamp = index(df1_xts_summed), coredata(df1_xts_summed))
df_final

            timestamp     T1     T2    T3 nrows
1 2015-11-05 10:24:00  90.31  89.03 26.37     2
2 2015-11-05 10:29:16 136.24 133.60 39.56     3
3 2015-11-05 10:32:00  45.96  44.85 13.23     1
4 2015-11-05 10:37:00  90.88  89.18 26.78     2
```

**Edit** if you want everything rounded at 5 minutes with these as the timestamps you need to do the following:

First step is to replace the timestamps with the 5 minute intervals, taking into account the starting minutes of the timestamps. For this I use the `ceiling_date` from the lubridate package and add to it the difference between the first values of the timestamp and the ceiling of the first value of the timestamp. This will return the last values of each interval. (If you want to use the start of the interval you need to use `floor_date`)

```
df1$timestamp <- lubridate::ceiling_date(df1$timestamp, "5 mins") + difftime(lubridate::ceiling_date(first(df1$timestamp), "5 mins"), first(df1$timestamp), unit = "secs")
```

Next the same xts code as before which returns the same data, but the timestamp is now the last value of the 5 minute intervals.

```
df1_xts <- as.xts(df1[, -4], order.by = df1$timestamp)
df1_xts_summed <- period.apply(df1_xts, ep, colSums)
df1_xts_summed$nrows <- period.apply(df1_xts$T1, endpoints(df1_xts, on = "minutes", k = 5), nrow)
df_final <- data.frame(timestamp = index(df1_xts_summed), coredata(df1_xts_summed))
df_final

            timestamp     T1     T2    T3 nrows
1 2015-11-05 10:27:00  90.31  89.03 26.37     2
2 2015-11-05 10:32:00 136.24 133.60 39.56     3
3 2015-11-05 10:37:00  45.96  44.85 13.23     1
4 2015-11-05 10:42:00  90.88  89.18 26.78     2
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(T1 = c(45.37, 44.94, 45.32, 45.46, 45.46, 45.96, 
45.52, 45.36), T2 = c(44.48, 44.55, 44.44, 44.51, 44.65, 44.85, 
44.56, 44.62), T3 = c(13, 13.37, 13.09, 13.29, 13.18, 13.23, 
13.53, 13.25), timestamp = c("2015-11-05 10:23:00", "2015-11-05 10:24:00", 
"2015-11-05 10:27:00", "2015-11-05 10:28:00", "2015-11-05 10:29:16", 
"2015-11-05 10:32:00", "2015-11-05 10:36:00", "2015-11-05 10:37:00"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I was expecting one value at every five minutes. The output in your answer has second value at 10:29:16 and the third value at 10:32:00.  I was expecting the next value at 10:34:00 or later.  Basically, what i am trying to do is to make the unequally spaced timeseries into euqally spaced time series at 5 min interval.

Comment: Period.apply returns the last value known in the interval. The 10:32 is the last available value in the 5 minute interval between 10:31 and 10:35. But if you want to return everything in 5 min interval, you really should specify your expected output. There are floor functions, but they round everything down to the nearest specified periode. If e.g. 5 minutes, your data would start at 10:20, not 10:23. Which might not exactly be what you want.

Comment: I added code to return the last datetime of the 5 minute intervals.

Comment: #phiver, I appreciate your answer here but was wondering if there is a solution you can think of which does not require an xts file.  My problem with using xts, is that I have character data (in particular, tickers) that seem to preclude the use of an xts file (which is kinda ironic since I thought xts files were often used in investment situations).  Any thoughts?

Comment: @WBarker, you might try the tidyquant package with the `tq_transmute` function. xts is often used in list objects and lapply to handle mutliple tickers in one go. There are multiple SO answers that show you how. If you need further help, please create a SO question with example and expected output.